# How to implement message listener in xmpp asmack?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I have created 3 activities. First is **loginactivity** to check login details.After Login is successfull it jumps to **displayactivity** which i used to show contacts of a person in a listview.After selecting any contact from listview it jumps to 3 activity which is **messageactivity** to show the chatting between 2 users. Now my question is where and how i implement messageListener So that i can show messages received from another user in **messageactivity** of a particular user?

Comment: when you click on particular Listview Item, go to messageactivity

Comment: yes, thats what i am doing but should i implement listener in messageactivity or displayactivity. And should i implement it using service or handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a PacketListener in your XMPPConnection instead of MessageListeners for your individual Chats. You will receive all messages sent to you (of the type specified by the filter, most probably Chats) through this Listener and then you can do whatever you want whether it's the person you are chatting with or somebody else.

Something like this:

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() 
{
   public void processPacket(Packet packet) 
   {
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      String body = message.getBody();
      String from = message.getFrom();
   }
}, filter);
```

Together with this you probably have to use sendPacket instead of sendMessage but it's pretty much the same, you won't have to worry about individual Chat instances. I hope it serves the purpose.

Comment: How should i implement this listener using service or thread or using any other method?

Comment: Listeners already have their own thread. What you should do is make the XMPPConnection global to your application so that it doesn't matter on which activity you are, it will always be active until you disconnect it. Create a class that has a static XMPPConnection object and each activity can make use of that XMPPConnection through that class. Hope that helps!

Comment: Tell me one last thing that when a message is received using listener then how can i display it on UI.Can i use broadcast here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a different question altogether, what you want to do is "update GUI from Thread", you should check stackoverflow as there are plenty of answers for that. Good luck!

Comment: can u please also post me a code for sending message using packet i have tried many times but getting some errors

Comment: Message msgObj = new Message(username, Message.Type.chat);
msgObj.setBody(body);

xmppConnection.sendPacket(msgObj);